# javascript variable to php file and back using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, post

i'm making an online barcode scanner application and having some issues with sending a javascript variable to php for my query , and getting it back in my html file with the data.

User scans barcode (studentNr)
studentnr --> variable is going to be posted to the php file.
in php file : query to compare with variable 
result of query --> back to the parameter of function(data)
print result. 
Sounds easy, but how do I do this correctly?

Index.html :

```
 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div>

<input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcode"> // BARCODE SCAN
<input type="text" id="student" placeholder="studentenNaam" size="30"> //NAME FROM DB
               <!--  <input type="text" id="barcode" placeholder="Waiting for barcode scan..." size="40">
               <input type="text" id="student" placeholder="studentenNaam" size="30">-->

         </div>
// just the script for scanning the barcode :

    <script>
     var barcodeParsed = null;
     var studentenNr = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pressed = false; 
    var chars = []; 
    $(window).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
            chars.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        }
        console.log(e.which + ":" + chars.join("|"));
        if (pressed == false) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (chars.length >= 10) {
                    var barcode = chars.join("");
                    console.log("Barcode Scanned: " + barcode);
                    barcodeParsed = barcode;
                    var barcodeParsing = barcodeParsed.substring(5,11);
                    $("#barcode").val("s" + barcodeParsing);
                    studentenNr = "s" + barcodeParsing;

                }
                chars = [];
                pressed = false;
            },500);
        }
        pressed = true;
    });
});

$("#barcode").keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        console.log("Prevent form submit.");

        $.post('testdb.php', {'studnr' :studentenNr}, function(data){ //POST JS VAR TO PHP FILE
           $('#student').html(data); //RECEIVE DATA FROM DB INTO ID ELEMENT
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});


     </script>

</body>
```

And in my testdb.php file it looks like this :

```
<?PHP

$studnr = htmlspecialchars($_POST['studnr']);
if(isset($studnr)){

    $user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "Student";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($hostname, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM student where studentenNr= '$studnr'"; 
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
/* Here needs the data to fetch*/
print $db_field['naam'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['studentenNr'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['voornaam'] . "<BR>";
}






mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}

}
```

The problem is i can't receive any data from my html file in to my php file, plus i don't know how i can put the received data back in to my html file. 
in the php-file..How do I write it back to the html ? 
Do I need to use Ajax,Jquery,.. 
Any other solutions ?

Thank you for helping me out !

### UPDATE

when adding this between the if(db_found) brackets I get an Internal Server Error 500.

```
 $sql = $db->prepare("select*from student where studentenNr= '$studnr' ");
$sql->execute($arraytest = array(':studnr' => studentenNr,naam );)


    $sql->execute(array(":studentenNr" => $studnr));

    $data = $sql->fetchAll();

    foreach($item as $data){
        print($item["naam"]);
        log($item["naam"]);
```

Comment: ajax is about the only way to go

Comment: I don't see why your code does not work. You are sending an AJAX POST call to the php file and using the result (html) in your first page.  **Are you getting errors?**  (optionally) To make your app more robust I would recommend formatting your PHP output in JSON and doing some processing in the HTML side.

Answer (score 1):

On your javascript you're sending **`studnr`** parameter:

```
$.post('testdb.php', {'studnr' :studentenNr}, function(data){
```

In your php script you trying to get the value from **`studentenNr`** parameter:

```
$studnr = htmlspecialchars($_POST['studentenNr']);
```

You need to cahnge your script to

```
$studnr = htmlspecialchars($_POST['studnr']);
```

---

**Edit:**

You're getting internal error because of this line:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("select*from student where studentenNr= '$studnr' ");
```

You need to prepare the SQL statement with the parameters and then bind them, so the line should be (something like):

```
$sql = $db->prepare("select * from student where studentenNr= :studnr");
$sql->execute(array(':studnr' => $studnr ));
```